異なるネットワークアドレス間でARP要求は到達可能ですか？
VLANについて次のページで学んでいたところ、このように書かれていました。これは、ネットワークアドレスが異なる端末同士でも、ARP要求が互いの端末に到達できることを意味している思います。たとえば図の左の「VLANがないときのL２通信」では、10.10.10.1/24から10.19.99.1/24へARP要求が到達できる、といったことです
https://milestone-of-se.nesuke.com/nw-basic/ethernet/vlan/

(VLAN を使わず) 同一ブロードキャストドメイン上で複数セグメントを持たせた場合、異なるセグメント間で Ethernet 通信は可能ですが、(ルーティングポイントが無い場合は) IP 通信 ( L3 通信 ) はできません。なのでそうなると VLAN の必要性は薄いんじゃないか？！と思うかもしれません。


一方で私は、こういうようなARP要求が、異なるネットワークアドレスを持つ端末へ到達できないのではないか、と考えています。というのも、次のサイトに示されている通りのことが、今回の上画像のケースでもいえると考えたためです（重要部分を太字で強調させていただきました）。
この記事によるとARP要求により行われるブロードキャストは、ARP要求を送信した端末に設定されているデフォルトゲートウェイにより行われます。そしてこの記事のケースではデフォルトゲートウェイはルーティングが行えないために、何も返答しないことになります。これにならえば、上図「VLANがないときのL２通信」では、ルーティングする端末が存在しないために、ARP要求は異なるネットワークアドレスまで届かない/何も返答されないのではないでしょうか？
https://www.itbook.info/study/p101.html

つまりPC-Aは、設定されているネットワーク以外のネットワークへの通信を 行う場合はデフォルトゲートウェイを使用するのですね。
今回の場合は、PC-Aは
　　IPアドレス：192.168.1.100 　　サブネットマスク：255.255.255.0
と設定されていますから、192.168.1.0～192.168.1.255以外への通信を行う
場合デフォルトゲートウェイを使用することになります。
そして、デフォルトゲートウェイである、192.168.1.1のノードは今回のネットワーク上に存在しないためARP要求をしたとしても返答がどこからも無いの です。


「ARP要求により行われるブロードキャストは、ARP要求を送信した端末に設定されているデフォルトゲートウェイにより行われ」とは、どういう状況を想定していますか？ARPを出すのはあくまでPC-Aですよ

参考元に書かれている「ネットワーク以外のネットワークへの通信を 行う場合はデフォルトゲートウェイを使用するのですね」と同様の意味合いです

VLANが設定されていないスイッチングハブはイーサネットフレームの送信元MACアドレスと宛先MACアドレスのみをみて、次のような動作をします。

宛先MACアドレスが

ブロードキャスト(FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF)の場合は、送られてきたポート以外の全てのポートにフレームを転送する。
ユニキャストでMACアドレステーブルに該当のアドレスが有る場合は、テーブルで結びつけられたポートにのみフレームを転送する。(そのポートがフレームが送られてきたポートである場合は破棄する。)
ユニキャストでMACアドレステーブルに該当のアドレスが無い場合は、送られてきたポート以外の全てのポートにフレームを転送する。


送信元MACアドレスが

ブロードキャスト(FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF)の場合は、何もしない。
ユニキャストの場合は、送られてきたポートを結びつけてMACアドレステーブルを更新する。



これがL2レベル(イーサネットのレベル)のみの動作であるためL2スイッチと言われます。この動作にIPやARPの中身は関係ありません。
全てのARP要求は宛先MACアドレスがブロードキャスト(FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF)であるため、スイッチングハブは全てのポートにフレームを転送し、全てのホストへそのフレームが到達します。この意味では全てのホストに「ARP要求が到達できる」といえます。ARP要求のフレームに受け取ったホストは、ARP内部にある送信元情報でARPテーブルを更新します。また、そのARP要求で求めている送信元IPアドレスが自分自身であれば、ARP要求をしたMACアドレス宛にARP応答を返すことになり、それは、そのホストへと到達することになります。
つまり、ARPはイーサネットレベルでの通信であるため、IPアドレスが同じネットワークであるかどうかは関係無く、ARPを使用したIPアドレスのMACアドレスの解決は「VLANが設定されていないスイッチングハブ」に接続されたホスト同士は可能と言うことです。ただ、それはARPのやりとりはできると言うだけで、TCP/IPで通信できるという意味ではありません。

ご回答ありがとうございます。もう少しお聞かせください。そのようなARP要求はTCP/IPのコマンドなしで行われうるのでしょうか？

pingコマンドのようなIPから上のレベルのプロトコルなしではARP要求が送出されない（かつ、L2スイッチが勝手にARP要求しあうことはない）という認識です。この認識が正しければ、デフォルトゲートウェイが設定されてない今回のケースではご回答いただいた一連の動作は行われないのではないかと考えた次第です。

他のIPアドレス宛のARP要求であっても、ブロードキャストであるため、全てのホストは受け取る事が可能であり、この状態が「ARP要求は到達可能」を意味します。「到達可能」「到達不可」のどちらですかと問われれば、「可能」というだけです。実際のIP通信でどのようなARP要求が行われるかは関係ありません。

また、ARP要求は」どのIPアドレスを求めずに「このIPアドレスを使っていませんか？」(ARP probe)や「自分のMACアドレスとIPアドレスはこれですよ」(GARP)というものがあります。これらは実際にどこのIPアドレスを求めるもでは無いため、全てのホストに届いて、それぞれが処理する必要があります。IPレベルでネットワークは関係ありません。

ARP は、L2 なので、到達可能です。

この記事によるとARP要求により行われるブロードキャストは、ARP要求を送信した端末に設定されているデフォルトゲートウェイにより行われます。そしてこの記事のケースではデフォルトゲートウェイはルーティングが行えないために、何も返答しないことになります。

この例では、ICMP(L3) を使用して、異なるセグメント間にルーターが存在しない場合にルーティングできないことを説明しています。本来あるべきデフォルトゲートウェイで設定したルーターが存在しないため、その先にあるはずの端末からの ARP 応答が返ってこないことを説明してます。
この時、ARP は、ブロードキャストなので、172.16.100 にも送信はされています。
VLAN の例では、物理的に接続されているため ARP が到達するという説明になっていると見えます。また、「同一ブロードキャストドメイン上で複数セグメントを持たせた場合」と前提があるので、同一ブロードキャストドメイン内であれば、ARP は、到達します。

ご回答ありがとうございます。引用元のサイトをみていただくと「異なるネットワークアドレスを持つ２台のPCがSW-HUBに接続されている場合、 この２台は通信が可能か否か？」と構成に関して言及されています。なので「物理的にセグメントが分割されていて、その間をルーターで接続している場合」には該当せず、同一ブロードキャストドメイン内での内容だと思いますが、いかがでしょうか？

確かに、私が見間違えていました。引用サイトの例では、セグメント間を SW-HUB で接続していますね。この場合は、同一ブロードキャスト ドメインとみなすことができます。この場合だと、ARP は、別のセグメントに到達します。

引用サイトについての回答を修正しました。

10.10.10.1/24から10.19.99.1/24へ通信を行おうとする場合、ネットワークアドレスが異なるのでデフォルトゲートウェイを介した(*1)通信となります。
10.10.10.1の端末は、10.19.99.1ではなく、デフォルトゲートウェイのアドレスに対するARP要求を送出します。
このとき、10.10.10.1と10.19.99.1が実際には同一ブロードキャストドメイン上に構成されていたとしたら、10.10.10.1がデフォルトゲートウェイのアドレスに対して行うARP要求も、10.19.99.1に到達します。到達はしますが、自身のアドレスではないので無視します。
「ARPリクエストが到達するか」という質問には「宛先」の視点が抜けています。

10.10.10.1 -> 10.19.99.1 のARPリクエストは10.19.99.1に到達するか

そもそもそのようなARPは送出されない(*2)


10.10.10.1 -> ゲートウェイのアドレスのARPリクエストは10.19.99.1に到達するか

到達するが自分とは関係ないので無視する



*1 厳密には、ルーティングテーブルを検索しマッチしたエントリのゲートウェイ
*2 デフォルトゲートウェイが設定されてない場合の挙動はOSによるがたいてい送出されないはず

皆さんの回答に補足します。
参考になれば幸いです。

以下の点は私も同じ意見です。

同一のブロードキャストドメインに異なるIPセグメントに属するIPアドレス(のPC等)が存在する場合、
一方が発信したARP要求は他方に到達する。理由は、ARPはL2プロトコルであり、IP通信の制約を受けないから。
例: IPセグメントAとIPセグメントBが同一ブロードキャストドメインに存在する場合、PC-A(10.10.10.1)が発信したARP要求はPC-B(10.19.99.1)に到達する。(※PC-AがARP要求を発信するのは、IPセグメントA内の他のIPアドレスに通信する場合)

IPセグメントA: 10.10.10.0/24 , PC-A: 10.10.10.1 (ゲートウェイ: 10.10.10.254)
IPセグメントB: 10.19.99.0/24 , PC-B: 10.19.99.1 (ゲートウェイ: 10.19.99.254)



加えて、
PC-AにPC-B向けのルーティング設定を行うことで、PC-AからPC-BへARP要求を発信することはできると考えます。
具体的には、10.10.10.1のIPを持つネットワークインターフェースに対し、10.19.99.1がリンクレベルで到達可能、と設定すれば可能と考えます。
設定例: Linuxの場合。(eth0に10.10.10.1が設定されている前提)

    ip route add 10.19.99.1/32 dev eth0

(設定後のルーティングテーブル)
# ip route show
10.19.99.1 dev eth0  scope link 
10.10.10.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.10.10.1 
127.0.0.0/8 dev lo  scope link 
default via 10.10.10.254 dev eth0  metric 1

＃この場合、PC-AからPC-BへIP通信(例: ping)を行うと、以下のような動作になると思います。
1. PC-AからPC-BのARP要求が発信される。
2. PC-BはPC-AからのARP要求を受け取るとPC-AにARP応答を返送する。
3. PC-AはPC-Bに`ECHO REQUEST`を送信する。(ルーティングテーブルが設定されているので、PC-B(MACアドレス)に直接送信する)
4. PC-Bは`ECHO REQUEST`を受け取るとPC-Aに`ECHO REPLY`を返送する。(ルーティングテーブルがないため、デフォルトゲートウェイ(10.19.99.254)に返信する)
5. ゲートウェイがルーティングしてくれればPC-Aに`ECHO REPLY`が到達する。


ARP要求が発信される契機については、別の質問と思いましたので、言及してません。
